# Install on Second Hard Drive with startup boot option?

Tags: 12.04, boot, bootloader

In theory, what I want to do is very simple, but I've done some google research and read some posts on this site and I'm still confused.

I want to keep win7 on my primary C:\ drive, and install Ubuntu (12.10) on a secondary drive (that I have yet to buy or install. I just want to be certain that I'm successful when I do this). If at all possible I'd also like it if when I start the computer I have the option to boot either Win7 or Ubuntu, like an account log in type thing where I just pick which drive I'm running with that day. And just to reiterate, I do ***not*** want to partition my C:\ drive or alter, change, or affect my Win7 system in any way.

The reason I'm still fairly uncertain about all of this, is that a lot of the guides I've read have been for earlier versions of Ubuntu. Also the vast majority of guides are about partitioning one drive to fit both OS'. I want two separate OS running from two separate drives that I can pick at boot. The guides I did find mentioned that there is some issue with the grub being installed on C:\ but the rest of the OS being installed on the other drive. Is this still the case? How do I avoid that?

Also, if it helps, I've been running 12.04lts on my laptop for a few months now in and out of class and I love it.

Finally, if you could please point me to a guide or write your answer in the form of a guide for a two year old that'd be awesome. I'm still an Ubuntu novice and I don't want to mess up my win7.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**How it works**

Each partitioned disk contain one small block called [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). It resides at the beginning of the disk.

Now, the OS inserts their code to MBR to load their own bootloader.
Windows does same, Linux does same.

They insert a small code pointing to actual location of bootloader. Like in Linux, This MBR contains `Stage1` of `GRUB` ([`GRUB`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) is a bootloader used in Linux) which loads a larger executable `Stage2` that may located in other partition.

If you install Windows, and then Linux, GRUB `Stage1` sits in MBR. Now other part of GRUB (the actual bootloader) contains the Windows bootloader location. Now when you select Windows from GRUB menu, Windows starts to load. This is called `chain loading` (GRUB loads first, then GRUB loads the Windows bootloader based on selection).

**Coming back to your question**

In your case, you have two MBR (because you have 2 hard disks).

Therefore, you have two options:

**Easiest Option**

- Create a partition on 2nd disk.
- Install Ubuntu on that partition & install GRUB on 2nd disk's MBR not on first disk's MBR. Be careful here. See below image (just for demo purpose), you need to do everything in **(probably) `sdb`**.
- You select your **already created `sdb` partition**, edit, assign mount point `/`, and file system type `ext4`
- Select boot loader location as `sdb` , not `sda` (see red colored section)

[image: bootloaderLocation]

- Once done, reboot and you will be booted to Windows 7.

It happens because, your **boot disk priority says to boot from first hard disk** (Where we didn't change anything).

So open BIOS, **change boot disk priority so that the disk containing Ubuntu comes first.**

- This time, GRUB will be loaded. And you can boot either OS.
- Remove the disk, Windows 7 will boot directly.
- Again plugin the 2nd disk, verify boot order from BIOS so that 2nd disk comes first. You can now boot any OS again.

**Another Option**

You can modify Windows bootloader also to load Ubuntu from 2nd disk. It is a bit harder, and since you don't want to touch Windows 7 at all, I am not recommending it.

**Note:** All tutorials available here talks about adding Ubuntu from same disk but different partition. I have not done it for across devices, you may need to adopt accordingly.

Here is a [tough guide](http://nerdy-notes.blogspot.in/2010/09/adding-ubuntu-to-windows-7-bootloader.html) to do so.

There is a great GUI tool to edit boot loader called [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (It is free for personal use). [Their guide](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) about setting up Ubuntu using Windows bootloader.

You can have more resource on it [Easy BCD Help: Dual boot Win7 and Ubuntu 11.10 -- "Add new Entry" for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124617/easy-bcd-help-dual-boot-win7-and-ubuntu-11-10-add-new-entry-for-ubuntu)

**I strongly recommend using GRUB as bootloader, as it is more flexible. May be you can [set Windows as default boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/52963/35775) option AND/OR [reduce timeout value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135113/how-to-change-the-time-for-os-selection-menu-in-grub/135116#135116).**

Comment: Okay, so I'd first have to format the new drive (ubuntu) and then create a partition on said drive.
Then install linux on sdb1 and the grub to sdb?
Also, If its easy.. I'd like the computer to prompt me to pick a disk on startup.. so if that means editing even windows bootload I'd be willing to think about it.. :D

Comment: @Arammil When you boot from sdb, GRUB will come up first and promt you to choose between Windows (take you to sda) or Ubuntu (in sdb) just as you want. You don't have to change the setting in BIOS every time for that.

Comment: yes you got it correct, just one thing you create partition if you need some part of hard disk to be available to windows. Or else you don't need to create partition. 2nd question : No disk selection is possible, as much as I know.. it depends on the BIOS. And pick up disk prompt is not equal to editing windows boot loader. I will add some guide for editing windows thing.

Comment: Well windows will be my main OS on this system, so is there a way that I can get the windows bootloader to prompt me to boot either Win7 or Ubuntu like grub will? Or if I use Grub to boot windows, will both disks be constantly running?

Comment: You can set [windows as default on to boot using grub](http://askubuntu.com/q/52963/35775). If you boot windows & don't use disk2, most probably it will suspend the disk for power saving. It all depends on OS. Nothing can be done here.

Comment: Yeah, I COULD edit the windows file.. but that seems pretty dangerous / f'd up. SO I'll probably just stick with GRUB. SO how exactly do I set grub to do that? And how would I then decide to boot Ubuntu when I wanted? 
Lastly: just to make sure, format my new drive, partition the drive, load grub on sdb and install the rest on sdb1. Then lastly I just need to edit the grub somehow???

Comment: Thanks for all the info everybody. I may post back after I get the second hard drive and let you know how it went/ post the actual process. Thanks.

Comment: you don't have to anything GRUB will search and add windows option to its menu. Edit grub only if you need to set windows as default boot. When you want to boot to ubuntu, just press up arrow key to select `ubuntu` and press enter to boot into it.

Comment: The only issue with the first one is that OCCASIONALLY, for certain windows updates, you will have to switch them back so it is the primary OS loading. You can restore after the update, but a few updates require this for whatever reason. I have had to do this several times.

Comment: I am confused, your answer says to be doing this whole thing (probably) in sdb, but your picture shows everything in sda. Is this just because your setup is in sda? Your chosen bootloader in the picture is on sda, should that just match the partition shown in the above table? Like if my Linux installation was going on sda, I would then have to change the bootloader install to sda?

Comment: So what do you choose to install Ubuntu on in the picture? You have dev/sda highlighted but then in a comment say to install it on dev/sda1. Do I need to go through the process of creating the sda1 partition if I want Ubuntu to take up the entire disk?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do this is as suggested above.  First, temporarily remove your first hard drive (the one with Windows on it).  Second, install Linux to the second hard drive (which for now is the only one connected).  Third, put your first hard drive back in, so that you now have two hard drives installed, each with its own OS.  From there, it's a simple matter of pressing a key at boot to select your boot drive.  For example, with a Dell machine you'd push the F12 key at boot, and this would bring up your menu to select the drive you want to boot from.

Answer (score 0):

I probably do it the backwards way but I use the boot menu to boot to Lubuntu (F12 on this System MB) When I installed Lubuntu I dis connected all other drives in the system. Then I installed the grub on the Lubuntu drive. Windows can't see the Lubuntu drive, but Lubuntu can see the windows drive so I can access files on other drives in the system.

Answer (score -1):

Disconnect your first drive with the Win 7 on it. That way you will be safe. Your computer probably has a boot selector function in it. Take a look in the setup and see that it is enabled.