# How do you install 13.04 on a separate hard drive?

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I currently run Windows 7 on my 1 TB hard drive, but also have a spare 320 GB hard drive.  I have a USB with Ubuntu 13.04 loaded on it, and my goal is to have Windows 7 on the 1 TB hard drive and Ubuntu on the 320 GB hard drive.  I know you are supposed to somehow set up partitions so that Ubuntu can install properly, but I don't know what the partitions should be and how big they should be.  Please advise on how I should install Ubuntu on the hard drive.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the following link [http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option

Comment: @JonathanRogiest Comments do not admit the use of the complete set of markdown. Read [here](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more information.

Comment: @Braiam How much storage do I allocate to each partition then?