# How to turn off hard drive when booting from USB?

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I want to install Ubuntu on a USB drive and found these instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option).

I want to do this, because I want to use my laptop when I am in a car or when I walk. So, I want to turn off my hard drive when booting from USB to prevent it to cause bad sectors, etc.

Now my question is: how to manually turn off the hard drive when booting from USB? Or, does it turn off when isn't in use or being mounted?

Comment: How much shaking do you expect? Most modern Laptops will handle a light beating, even with the disk spinning. The disk should be powered, but idle when you don't mount it.

Comment: If the disk is idle (despite it is on) is shaking it will damage it?

Comment: Not more than it would be when turned on. You can still crash a head with the disk powered off. But as I mentioned, unless you are driving on very uneven surfaces or trip constantly when taking a walk, modern HDDs wouldn't mind.

Comment: I think you mean: not more than it would be when turned off. does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to take your hard disk to enter **standby** mode (or to **sleep** mode). *This gets HDD to spin down and park the heads to **landing zones** so that the chances of a **head crash** is nullified*.

1. Boot the Ubuntu liveCD/DVD/USB.
2. If the HDD that you're trying to take to standby mode has a *swap-partition* (likely if you have Ubuntu installed in your HDD as well), turn it off.

   `sudo swapoff -a` (This turns off all devices marked as *swap*)
3. Now to make your HDD enter low power consumption **standby** mode:

   `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdX` where *sdX* is the target HDD, and **X** in *sdX* should be replaced appropriately (with a, b, c, ..., z); assuming it to be *sda*, the command would look like this: `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda`

   Or you could make your HDD enter the lowest power consumption **sleep** mode, causing it to *shut down* completely with:

   `sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdX` (*sdX* should be the target device)

That's it! You can then continue using your live Ubuntu session.

<sup>[(Note: Modern laptops use "self-park" for better & safe portability.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_crash#Laptops)</sup>

---

PS. This method of putting a HDD to standby mode can prove helpful also when you want to be a little ***economical on power consumption***. Especially in desktop computers, if you have *more that one* internal HDDs, you can *power down those which you use very less than often*.