# Automatically booting Ubuntu from new SSD rather than Windows on old HDD?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, ssd

So I got Ubuntu working. Problem is if I keep both my SSD and HDD drive connected to the motherboard, Windows automatically starts up completely disregarding Ubuntu.

At the moment, i'd like both OSs present for testing. I couldn't install two OSs on my new SSD because I don't have the installation CD for Windows.

How can I set Ubuntu as default boot up and is there a way to choose between the two hard drives what OS to use on powering up the computer?

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, try pressing the boot selection key (usually F12) when booting up. It will list all attached bootable devices (even USB if applicable/available). Just select the desired device and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose what HDD to boot from in BIOS setup.

To enter BIOS setup hit F2 or Del (or maybe some other key) when powering up your computer.

The menu you need is named something like Boot or Boot Priority or maybe you'll need to change HDD priority (also in BIOS setup).

After you manage to boot from your SSD (where Ubuntu is installed) you'll probably see grub boot menu, where you should be able to choose which OS to boot. If not you should try configuring grub after booting Ubuntu.

It would be also usefull for you to read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option) question and answers.