# Is it possible to install Linux side by side with Windows 7, but on the other drive, part of which is occupied by ntfs partition?

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

So my situation is this: I have 2 Drives. 1 HDD(1TB) 1 SSD(about 230GB). I use SSD completely for Windows 7(with one partition only). I also use big part of HDD as NTFS storage for that windows(I called it 'Data'). I want to install Ubuntu on whats left. Here is a screenshot:

My Drives:
[image]

Is it possible to do it like that? If so, what options I need to select during drive questions in order not to kill MBR and be able to load to both Windows and Linux?

Comment: If you do not unplug SSD, you can install to sdb using Something Else install option and manually create / (root) as ext4 format. Also should create swap. But you must use combo box on partitioning screen and change grub install location to HDD drive. Otherwise grub always installs to drive seen as sda, and you want to keep Windows boot loader in SSD. http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy to do.

Now in your question you say:

> If so, what options I need to select during drive questions in order
> not to kill MBR and be able to load to both Windows and Linux?

You are going to have to install GRUB to the MBR of one of your disks.

- If you install it to the MBR of your SSD, you won't have to change anything to get the dual-boot working properly.
- If you install GRUB to the MBR of your HDD, you will have to alter the boot order in your BIOS so that the HDD is booted before the SSD.

Both are perfectly valid options.

Please leave a comment under my answer with which option you want to do, and also with a picture from the ["Something Else" installation option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh3pu.png), and I'll be more than happy to guide you through the partition setup.

## Do not select "install alongside Windows"!
Select "something else", as shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh3pu.png).

#### I need you to take a picture of what this screen looks like for you in the installer:

[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ifK5Z

Comment: So i create linux + swap partition on free space. Lets say i want SSD for boot record. Which of those down there I select?

Comment: @KostyantynDavydov - Give me a sec to look at your picture.

Comment: P.S. Every time i try to install Ubuntu with CD/DVD drive plugged in, I don't even get to the installation and I get stuck here: http://imgur.com/a/D6dzS   Why does that happen? So I avoid that by installing from USB + unplugging Optical drive.

Comment: @KostyantynDavydov - Okay, so you want to format the free space under `/dev/sda` as EXT4 and set the mount point as `/`. Then, for where it asks you where to install GRUB, select `/dev/sda`.

Comment: @KostyantynDavydov - As for why that happens with the optical drive, no idea. That would be a good separate question to ask here.

Comment: @KostyantynDavydov - Also, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it. (After you've verified that everything works of course)

Comment: But isn't SDA HDD?

Comment: @KostyantynDavydov - Oh, I'm so sorry! You are correct; you're going to want to install GRUB to `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: I will probably clone bootrecord later to both drives anyway :). Anyways thanks. I will try installing later today and then report back/accept your answer!

Comment: @KostyantynDavydov - Okay! P.S. I do **not** recommend you clone the bootrecord.

Comment: Why not :)? I usually do that when i have two Windows OS installed using EasyBCD.

Comment: @KostyantynDavydov - Just because of the way GRUB works, that might cause some problems. But you can try that if you want, but just know there's a possibility that it will make your system unbootable.