# Cannot find grub.efi after installing Ubuntu in a different driver partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have two hard drives, one of which already contains Window 10.
I installed Ubuntu on sdb following these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option). After switching the boot order to my second drive, however, the computer reports that it cannot find grub.efi

To fix it, I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) instruction. But grub repair was enable to fix my issue, and it yield [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/26295166/) report instead.

I'm now writing this from a USB stick, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If your EFI partition is set up with .../EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi as a copy of shimx64.efi (check the sizes), then there needs to be a copy of grubx64.efi in that same directory, .../EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi.

---

While running the USB, start a terminal (ctrl alt t, or use the dash launcher for gnome terminal).  Make a directory in /mnt to mount the second hard disk:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/d2
```

Mount the second partition of sdb there:

```
sudo mount -tvfat /dev/sdb2 /mnt/d2
```

Copy the missing file:

```
sudo cp /mnt/d2/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/d2/EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi
```

unmount the disk partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/d2
```

Try rebooting the sdb disk now.  If you get the same error, repeat on sda, it looks like it's missing there too.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly going on when you boot? Do you arrive at grub?

If not it must be a bios issue, the highest priority of the boot should be on ubuntu so it will give you the grub