# Would removing my 1st drive be the best way to set up Ubuntu 2204 on a 2nd drive with full disk encryption (while preserving Windows on my 1st drive?)

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, encryption

I have a laptop with two SSDs. The primary SSD is running Windows (which I'm planning to keep in place for now), but I'd like to install Ubuntu 22.04 on the secondary SSD with full disk encryption.

Within the install menu, I didn't see an option to install Ubuntu with full disk encryption on the secondary disk. However, [this answer from 2016](https://askubuntu.com/a/730301/1685413) suggests that I could just unscrew my primary drive from my laptop, install Ubuntu, reinstall the second drive, and then choose between the two operating systems at boot time.

Would this still work for Ubuntu 22.04? I know that there are some ways to manually configure system-wide encryption, but for a newcomer to Ubuntu like me, just temporarily taking the primary SSD out of my computer might be the easiest solution.

Comment: You can't break a Windows SSD while installing Ubuntu to another SSD if it is not plugged in.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you for sharing that helpful resource! I ended up unscrewing the drive with Windows on it, which allowed me to install Ubuntu 22.04 with full disc encryption without any issues.