# Windows 7/Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot woes

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, windows-7

I tried dual-booting Windows/Ubuntu. I first set up partitions using GParted:

```
/dev/sda1      ext4      Ubuntu      Primary
/dev/sda2      ntfs      Windows     Primary
/dev/sda3      ntfs      Data        Primary
/dev/sda5      swap      Swap        Logical (in /dev/sda4 Extended)
```

Their physical order on disk is the same. I haven't given the size as I don't think it matters.

Then I installed Ubuntu (with the bootloader in `/dev/sda`), then Windows (in `/dev/sda2`).

I tried to use EasyBCD to boot into Ubuntu (added an entry). No dice. Used a live CD to do [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/197513/89369) (I had to use the `--force` flag, something about blocks) using the Windows Bootloader as main, then re-created the entry, and wrote the bootloader to MBR for good measure. Still doesn't work. I want to use the Win7 bootloader as main.

All I get each time when I select Ubuntu is this (written in a DOS font): `Try (hd0,0): EXT2: _`, where the underscore is a blinking cursor.

Comment: Please indicate your BootInfo URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you're using EasyBCD. Add an entry that's Linux/BSD -> Wubi. If that doesn't work, use GRUB 2 instead of Wubi. FINALLY, if it still doesn't work, use GRUB legacy. If it STILL doesn't work, my well is dry. I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried GRUB 2 and GRUB. I don't think Wubi would help since this is a dedicated (non-Wubi) installation.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Wubi is used when dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu. As described, this is in fact a Wubi installation. Try using Wubi, and say whether it works or not.

Comment: Side note, you said Windows was your main bootloader--won't work. You need GRUB to load the Windows bootloader.

Comment: Have you got a source for that last claim? I'd love to read the reason. I distinctly remember I used another bootloader (not really the Windows one) to load Ubuntu and it worked.

Comment: It's from my own experience. I could never get the Windows bootloader to load Ubuntu, but I could always get GRUB to load the Windows bootloader. One partition has GRUB, one has Windows. GRUB forwards you to the Windows partition, where the Windows bootloader takes over. The Windows bootloader cannot do this, or at least it doesn't do it properly.